# Triangle geometry

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $P$ be a point inside it such that $AP$, $BP$ and $CP$ meet sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ in points $D$, $E$ and $F$, respectively. Given that $AP=a$, $BP=b$, $CP=c$, $PD=PE=PF=3$ and $a+b+c=43$, how to find $abc$?

I imagined a circle centered in $P$ and passing through $D,$, $E$ and $F$. Moreover, I tried to use Ceva's theorem but I did not find it useful. I also find it strange that the value of $abc$ is an invariant given $a+b+c$. For this to happen, they have to appear in the same equation and this equation has to be dimensionally homogeneous, i.e., $abc$ has dimension of length cubed. So $a+b+c$ has to appear cubed in this equation or multiplied by some lengths given in the problem, like $PD=PE=PF=3$ (length units).

Comment: I imagined a circle centered in P passing through D, E and F, but unfortunately I wasn't able to reach any conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $PD=PE=PF=r$. If $PP_1$ and $AA_1$ are altitudes dropped to $BC$ from $P$ and $A$ respectively, then $\triangle PDP_1 \sim \triangle ADA_1$. Therefore,

$$\frac {S_{\triangle PBC}} {S_{\triangle ABC}} = \frac {\frac 1 2 PP_1 \cdot BC} {\frac 1 2 AA_1 \cdot BC} = \frac {PP_1}{AA_1}= \frac {PD} {AD} = \frac r {a+r}.$$ Similarly, $\dfrac {S_{\triangle PCA}} {S_{\triangle ABC}} = \dfrac r {b + r}$ and $\dfrac {S_{\triangle PAB}} {S_{\triangle ABC}} = \dfrac r {c + r}$. From this, we have: $$\frac r {a+r} + \frac r {b+r} + \frac r {c+r} = \frac {S_{\triangle PBC} + S_{\triangle PCA} + S_{\triangle PAB}} {S_{\triangle ABC}} = 1.$$ Doing some simple algebra, $r((b+r)(c+r)+(a+r)(c+r)+(a+r)(b+r))=(a+r)(b+r)(c+r)$ or $r(3r^2+2r(a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ac))=r^3+r^2(a+b+c)+r(ab+bc+ca)+abc$. Thus, $$abc=2r^3+r^2(a+b+c)=r^2(2r+(a+b+c))=3^2(2 \cdot 3 + 43)=441.$$

Comment: Neat. As a comment, $S_1 + S_2 + S_3 = S_{ABC}$ uses the condition that $P$ is inside the triangle; if $P$ is outside, the value of $a b c$ is not unique.

Comment: @Maxim I agree, but that condition was stipulated unequivocally in the question, so I used it.